# Spark hung when querying Hive external table connected to Hbase

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hbase

We have created a Hive external table that is connected to Hbase, but when we try to access the table in Spark-Shell, by doing a simple query as follows,

Scala> sqlContext.sql("Select * from [Hive-External-Table]).count()

The latter part of the log looks like this:

```
15/10/13 17:13:08 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server BData-h1/10.10.10.82:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/10/13 17:13:08 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.10.10.82:34108, server: BData-h1/10.10.10.82:2181
15/10/13 17:13:08 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server BData-h1/10.10.10.82:2181, sessionid = 0x1505f6805c70281, negotiated timeout = 60000
15/10/13 17:13:09 INFO RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "analytics_demo".
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at SparkPlan.scala:83
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at SparkPlan.scala:83) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(collect at SparkPlan.scala:83)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at SparkPlan.scala:83), which has no missing parents
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(16512) called with curMem=601741, maxMem=278302556
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 16.1 KB, free 264.8 MB)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(8676) called with curMem=618253, maxMem=278302556
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 8.5 KB, free 264.8 MB)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on BData-h1:35111 (size: 8.5 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at SparkPlan.scala:83)
15/10/13 17:13:24 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/10/13 17:13:25 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, BData-h2, RACK_LOCAL, 1424 bytes)
15/10/13 17:13:25 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on BData-h2:37159 (size: 8.5 KB, free: 530.3 MB)
15/10/13 17:13:27 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on BData-h2:37159 (size: 42.8 KB, free: 530.2 MB)
```

The system just hung right there.

If we query a Hive managed table, it will return the result just fine.

We tried many things, but have no luck. Is there anybody who can shed some light on this issue for us?

Comment: Some more information: we got this error

Comment: Some more information: we eventually got this error: ob aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, BData-h2): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for in analytics_demo after 35 tries. analytics_demo is the external Hive table name.

Comment: For spark-shell/spark-sql to be able to access hive external tables created on top of hbase table, it requires information regarding hbase configuration. Add --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf/"' while starting spark shell. Over here, hbase-site.xml is present under /etc/hbase/conf